# what's the function of the Short line in the mysql

Tags: mysql

I never saw someone use `-` in the mysql. What's that meaning?

And what's the difference between

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=1-SLEEP(15)
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=1 and SLEEP(15)
```

use the first one in DVWA(1.0.7),I can feel the delay,and I can get the result

but use the another one have no result shown when I also feel the delay.

so what's the `-` function?

Comment: Ever heard of arithmetic operators? "-" is the opposite of "+".

Comment: First example: `SLEEP(15)` always returns `0`, and will be executed for each record examined, Since `SLEEP(15)` returns `0`, you're checking `id=1-0`, so `id=1` will always be checked. The output of the query will be the same as `SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=1;`, just much slower (15+ seconds per record). Second example: the `SLEEP(15)` will only execute if `id=1` is true (the `and` expression is already false if `id=1` is not true), and since `SLEEP(15)` always returns `0`, then the entire `WHERE` expression is false, so no results from the `SELECT`.

Comment: Thank you very much,It's meaning that the first example just check the `id=1-0`(1-0 is same to 1),and it's true so i get delay,then in second example will check two conditions (one is `id=1`,one is return from sleep()),and sleep return 0 so always is false.

Comment: SLEEP() does not return 0 if the query was interrupted or timed out. See documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for the clarification. I should have said *normally* (as in under normal circumstances) rather than *always*.